# Optimized water droplet formation

Tags: fluid-mechanics, liquid, air, microfluidics

What is the best way to "shatter" a water drop falling purely under gravity if the objective is to break it into as many droplets and as fine (smallest diameter) as possible? Should the surface be perpendicular to the direction of the falling drop? What would the best surface texture be: smooth, irregular, matt, wet or dry? What would be a typical droplet size distribution i.e., would some be in the micron size range? Would sizes similar to aerosol produced by spray nozzles and ionizers be at all possible?

Comment: Have you tried any method you've mentioned and observed the results? What is the intended application?

Comment: there are papers on this... look up droplet splashing, perhaps vs hydrophobic or superhydrophobic surfaces. vibrating or rotating surface would help. It would be hard to beat an ultrasonic or electrospray device tho

Comment: If you want droplets similar in size to those produced by spray nozzles then use one. If not test a caburetor.

Comment: @SolarMike  I believe spray nozzles, as well as the injectors in a carburator, depend on a feed pressure much higher than what a falling droplet can apply.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft carbuetors use a venturi where the fuel is drawn in due to a pressure below atmospheric, combined the the lower air pressure feeding the carb due to the pressure drop across the filter.

Comment: @SolarMike ahh, yes,  for some reason I was thinking of fuel-injection systems.  Apologies

Comment: extremely hot.  if you need to scatter water molecules, take it to steam.

Answer (score 1):

There is research on the impact of water droplets on deep liquids and solid surfaces.

It seems the most significant factor in the outcome of the collision and its rather short span, in the range of a few milliseconds, is the height of the drop then the droplet's initial size.

Here is one research with detailed diagrams and speed shutter photography. It explains the crown formation, dispersion, and electrical charges due to the use of different solutes as the liquid.

.

[droplets impact](https://www.jstor.org/stable/73991)
[image: droplet]